# Why ASP.NET Core template nuget is not compatible?

Tags: c#, templates, asp.net-core

I created a nuget package for ASP NET Core app template. But when I try to install this:

```
dotnet new -i mytemplate -n myprojectname
```

I get this error:

> error NU1202: Package mytemplate 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package mytemplate 1.0.0
>   supports: netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)

I don't understand this, what is not compatible ? Im just tried to create new app from template.

Comment: I think your package targets a higher version of .NETCore than the project you're trying to install it on.

Comment: How did you create your nuget package? I made a test with [Create a custom template for dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/create-custom-template#use-nuget-distribution), but fail to reproduce your issue. Share us detail steps and project which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou I created it with dotnet pack.

Comment: @Dortimer But I'm trying to create new application from template, im not installing anything on project.

Comment: @TjDillashawI think project templates still have a .Net Framework version that they target though.